# Javascript to set desktop wallpaper

Tags: javascript, html, desktop, wallpaper

I need to make a button or link to set a picture as the desktop wallpaper after clicking. Can this be achieved with JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript can't override user system preferences and SO is not a "gimme the code" site

Comment: I don't get why this question is beeing downvoted. Just because this question is kind of ingenuous it's not a bad question at all. In my opinion it actually is useful and clear. Upvoting / Downvoting isn't ment to rate the knowledge of the owner. (IMHO)

Answer (score 5):

Not possible in JS, you don't get access to the filesystem or any system preferences.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. It would be very dangerous if you could do such system near operations through JavaScript.